# VBA Delete Row with Contain Text

Tags: excel, vba, click, delete-row

I have prepared VBA code to delete row that contain word "Delete". The VBA is working but right now, I don't want the VBA to delete row number 8 even it wrote delete. Kindly assist.

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners6_Click()
    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A8:A9").Select
Range("A9").Activate
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "Delete" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image: Sample Images of the Excel table]

I have prepared VBA code to delete row that contain word "Delete". The VBA is working but right now, I don't want the VBA to delete row number 8 even it wrote delete. Kindly assist. When i click delete button, i want it to delete row below that contain "Delete" except row no 8.

[image: Result expected images]

Comment: Is column `A` a helper column (a column you'd rather not have)? I mean, you don't need it if you will always delete all **data** rows except the first. Are you considering clearing the contents in the first **data** row? The row above the last (the total row) also seems useless. Do you really need it? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tweak the `If` statement:

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners6_Click()
    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A8:A9").Select
Range("A9").Activate
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "Delete" And i <> 8 Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looping from the last row of the sheet all the way up to row 1 of the sheet, that is the instruction in this line:

```
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
```

If you want to stop at the 9th row of the sheet, change that line to 9:

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners6_Click()
    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A8:A9").Select
Range("A9").Activate
    For i = Last To 9 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "Delete" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```